# Passing an onClick handler as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a calculator app in React with CodePen, but I'm having trouble passing an onClick handler to one of the number buttons. The error I each time I click a number buttons is :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClick')`

What is the proper way to pass an onClick handler as a prop from a parent component to a child component? I'm trying to use the same method used in the [official React tutorial](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ybbQJX?editors=0010). Here's my code:

```
function NumberButton(props){ // click handler is passed as prop from the Calculator
  return(
    <button className='square' onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
      {props.number}
    </button>
  );
}

function OperatorButton(props){
  return(
    <button className='square' onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
      {props.operation}
    </button>
  );
}

class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      value_1:"",
      value_2:"",
      operation:null,
      display:null
    }
  }
  
  renderNumberButton(x){ //This function will render each number button using the number it gets passed as a prop
    return(
      <NumberButton 
        className='square'
        number={x} 
        onClick={() => this.numberClick(x)}
      /> 
    ); 
  }
  
  renderOperatorButton(y){ //function will render each operator function with the operator it gets passed as a prop
    return(
      <OperatorButton 
        operation={y} 
        onClick={() => this.operatorClick(y)}
      />
    );
  }
  
  numberClick(x){ 
    if (this.state.operation == null){ //if an operation hasn't been chosen, update value_1
      this.setState({
        value1:this.state.value_1.Concat(x),
        display: this.state.value_1
      })
    } else { //if an operation has been chosen, update value_2
      this.setState({ 
        value_2:this.state.value_2.Concat(x),
        display:this.state.value_2
      })
    }
  }
  
  operatorClick(y){
    this.setState({
      operation:y,
      display:this.state.value_2
    })
  }
  
  resetCalculator(){
    this.setState({
      value_1:null,
      operation:null,
      value_2:null
    })
  }
  
  
  
  render(){
    const array=[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    const numberButtons=array.map(x => this.renderNumberButton(x)) //renders the number buttons from this array instead of hard coding each one 
    
    return(
      <div>
        <div className='screen'>
          {this.state.display}
        </div>
        
        
        <div>
          {numberButtons.slice(0,3)}
        </div>

        <div>
          {numberButtons.slice(3,6)}
          <button
            className='square'
            onClick={() => this.resetCalculator}
          >
            clr
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          {numberButtons.slice(6, 10)}
          <button className='square'>
            =
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <div>
          {this.renderOperatorButton('+')}
          {this.renderOperatorButton('-')}
          {this.renderOperatorButton('x')}
          {this.renderOperatorButton('/')}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root=ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Calculator />)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `this` from the `NumberButton` and `OperatorButton`.

```
onClick={() => props.conClick()}
```

`NumberButton` and `OperatorButton` are the `functional component` and there is no `this`.

You can check this [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-wind-f50s77?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error. I overlooked the fact that the official React tutorial used only class-based components.